# Archiving shared mailboxes on Office365?

Tags: exchange-server, office365

We have a shared mailbox with over 1000 folders on our Office 365 environment. We can't use the caching functionality which causes Outlook to be extremely slow. In fact, our users that use these shared mailboxes are almost unable to work.

Is there software arround that can archive these e-mails? I mean, we need some software that creates something like a PST-file that is accessible for everyone that is using the shared mailboxes. They can then move the 1000+ folders to this archive/PST so that they can enable caching mode which makes Outlook fast again.

Comment: I think this question is not really about programming and should be moved to [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Keluro](https://keluro.com/) which is a solution for what you want to achieve but not based on shared mailboxes (although shared mailbox support is coming soon). *Disclaimer:* I am principal developer and CTO of Keluro.

Comment: I didn't know where to post it, I'm sorry. Unfortunately it doesn't work with shared mailboxes, the same goes for MailStore. I really need something that works with a shared mailbox.